# Working with WINAPI with couple of threads

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

I've been working on WinAPI for a while, and I noticed that whenever I try to use WINAPI functions (such as create buttons/windows / update listview and such) inside a thread which isn't the main thread, it just wont show up.

So for example, if I want to add items to a ListView, and I call a function that takes a string and adds it to the listview, if I call the function from the main thread, it'll work great, but if I call it from a different thread, it won't work at all.

What can I do?

Comment: You could show some code. And define "won't work at all".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with most (all?) GUI systems you need to update the GUI from the thread that owns the window (usually the main thread). You need to find a way to communicate between the two threads. In Win32 my preferred way is to send a [user message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644931%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to the GUI thread (via [PostMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) and update accordingly. You will need to ensure there's no concurrent access to data you send between them, for example protect global data with a Critical Section or something.

A simple example, semi pseudo code:

```
#define WM_MY_MESSAGE WM_USER+1

thread
{
    do some number crunching...
    // inform user
    EnterCriticalSection(&MessageCrit);
    strncpy(StatusMessageText, "Crunching away...", ARRAYSIZE(StatusMessageText));
    LeaveCriticalSection(&MessageCrit);
    PostMessage(hwndMain, WM_MY_MESSAGE, 0, 0); // You can utilize the params to your hearts content: structures, enums, etc...
}

guithread
{
switch (message)
{
case WM_INITDIALOG: // etc - whatever is in your normal message handler
    break;
case WM_MY_MESSAGE:
    ListView_InsertItem(...); // etc
    EnterCriticalSection(&MessageCrit); // Protect the global data
    ListView_SetItemText(item, StatusMessageText);
    LeaveCriticalSection(&MessageCrit);    
    break;
}
}
```

Comment: I don't think it has to be the *main* thread. It just has to be the thread that *created* the component, or possibly the thread that contains the message pump.

Comment: Actually, sending messages to windows on other threads *is* possible, and *the* way to do inter-thread communication on Windows. Posting a message to the thread, who then posts the same message to the window, is redundant. However, it is not possible to e.g. create a window on a thread with another thread's window as its parent.

Comment: then, if I want to add an item to a list view through a differnt thread, what do I write in the `PostMessage` function?

Comment: It should just work - sounds like your problem is somewhere else. Can you post code?

Comment: when I use `ListView_InsertItem` and `ListView_SetItemText` inside a thread who isnt the main thread, it doesnt work at all (and it is getting called), while being in the main thread does work.. so I dont think I have an error

Comment: You need to call ListView_InsertItem from the thread that created it. You can *post* a message from any thread to any window -just be sure to protect the data you want to access from both.

Comment: `ListView_InsertItem` calls `SendMessage`. For `SendMessage` to work, you (probably?) need a functional message pump, as the first comment on this thread says. Try using `PostMessage` directly, instead of using the `ListView_` macros - or creating the message pump by calling `PeekMessage` in your thread.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It's the thread associated the window, which is the thread that created it.

Comment: @jlahd It certainly is possible for a window to be parented by a window from another thread. They can even be parented by windows from other processes. It's no fun mind you. But it is possible.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan OK, I stand corrected :) IIRC, it was not possible on some earlier version of Windows.

Comment: @noelicus No that is not true. Messages are always dispatched by the thread that owns the window.

Comment: @jlahd No, it's always been possible.

Answer (score 0):

You should either use `PostMessage`:

```
static LVITEM lvi = { ... };
PostMessage( myListView, LVM_INSERTITEM, 0, (LPARAM)&lvi );
```

or, if you need the return value, create a message pump for your thread first:

```
MSG msg;
PeekMessage( &msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE );
static LVITEM lvi = { ... };
ListView_InsertItem( myListView, &lvi );
```

If you use `PostMessage`, be sure to keep the memory alive also after `PostMessage` returns, as the message is processed asynchronously by your main thread.

Comment: I cannot understand why you would use `PostMessage` with `LVM_INSERTITEM`. Can you explain why.

Comment: To not block the posting thread for the duration of the main window's thread processing the message.

Comment: But doing so gives you a gigantic lifetime management issue with the `LVITEM` struct.

Comment: That depends on the underlying architecture. The `LVITEM` struct could, for example, be a part of an aggregate struct that represents a work item, owned by the worker thread, that always corresponds to one line in a list view.

Comment: More common is that it is a local. Keeping around global `LVITEM` objects would be a sign of poor design.

Comment: One could argue that accessing the list view from another thread is a sign of poor design as such. However, that's not the point I'm trying to make here; my point is that posting and sending messages from another thread directly to the list view owned by the main thread *should* work as such - it is not restricted by Windows.